React Native 0.76.2 expo. ScrollView doesn't work on android but works in expo app
I have modal component with this return section:
import {Modal, SafeAreaView, ScrollView, View, Text} from "react-native";


return (
        <Modal visible={open}
               animationType='slide'
               presentationStyle='pageSheet'
               onRequestClose={close}
        >
            <SafeAreaView>
                <ScrollView>
                  <View><Text>123</Text></View>
                  <View><Text>123</Text></View>
                  <View><Text>123</Text></View>
                  ...
                </ScrollView>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </Modal>
    )

After run: eas build --platform android --profile preview scroll doesn't work in this modal, but on IOS or Expo app it works well.
